# Connecting to website using Java - Dealing with SSL plaintext error, proxies, and more

Tags: java, ssl

I understand how to connect to normal websites using tools such as JSoup or even base Java and have done so before. Unfortunately, now I am trying to connect to a specific website that is giving me too many problems for me to be able to fix without thoroughly studying networking protocol.

I am trying to make a simple application that for the time being needs to connect to the follow website in order to log in:

lms.topicanative.edu.vn

The problem is, I can't even connect to the site. Using methods that have worked for me in the past lead to an error reading:

```
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I've tried using Java itself and manually setting a proxy but received timeout errors. I can't properly bug fix this because frankly I don't know all of the steps that could fail. I'm hoping someone with more knowledge in this subject could tell me what makes the website I need to connect to so difficult, and how can I connect to it?

Here is what I have tried so far and the corresponding errors:

Method 1: JSoup
Code:

```
Document logInPage = Jsoup.connect("https://lms.topicanative.edu.vn").get();
```

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Method 2: Java
Code:

```
  URL logInURL = new URL("https://lms.topicanative.edu.vn");

  SocketAddress logInSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("123.31.18.20"), 8080);
  Proxy logInProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, logInSocketAddress);
  HttpsURLConnection logInPageConn = (HttpsURLConnection)logInURL.openConnection(logInProxy);
  System.out.println(logInPageConn.getResponseCode());
```

Error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

**Update**

I have since revised the code to the following:

Code:

```
URL logInURL = new URL("https://lms.topicanative.edu.vn");
SocketAddress logInSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("123.31.18.20"), 443);
Proxy logInProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, logInSocketAddress);
HttpsURLConnection logInPageConn = (HttpsURLConnection)logInURL.openConnection(logInProxy);
System.out.println(logInPageConn.getResponseCode());
```

Error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Comment: Alright, I have edited in the code an errors. I am kind of new so I don't know if people want to see the full stack trace, so for now I have just posted the message.

Comment: Are you sure target Proxy is accepting connection over secure protocol?Try HTTP instead.

Comment: I just pinged it using inet.isReachable(5000) and it is reachable. Perhaps I put in the wrong port number?

Comment: I tried changing it to HTTP and have still received the connection time out error. I appreciate you troubleshooting this with me btw.

Comment: I have changed the port number from a plain text one to one appropriate for https. I now receive a completely new error which is called "Unexpected end of file from server" I may need to make a new post for this. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting after importing the SSL certificate and password.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a more elaborate library for Http connection such as Okhttp.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Normal Https connections should work out of the box.

Refer their documentation on advanced HTTPS configuration:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS